# How Does Azure Caching Store Data With References Between Objects

Tags: azure, azure-caching

I am wondering about how Azure Caching stores data where there are references between  objects.

For example consider a structure which contains ObjectA, and ObjectA has ObjectB and ObjectC as properties, and ObjectC also has a property called ObjectB.

If I cache ObjectA, does ObjectB get cached twice - once as a property of ObjectA and once as a property of ObjectC, or does Azure Caching also store the references?

All the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serializers nowadays are pretty smart. There should not be a duplicate or infinite serialization issues with caching of an object that has circular references between child objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not talking about circular references. I'm just trying to get to the bottom of whether there would be duplication or not.

Comment: There would not be.  Circular references just fall under similar rule.